# how to select inner element of child using parent in jquery

Tags: jquery, select

If the DOM has a `div` element with `class='div-outer'` like the following, then how can I access inner elements say anchor tags which is deep inside the children of outer div?

EX:

```
<div class='div-outer'>
  <span>
    <span>
      ...
               <a></a>  (at n-th depth)
      ...
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: is it `<div class='div-outer'>`?

Comment: yes.. I forgot to mention..

Comment: Seriously, did you search for it before asking it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Deep inside the children of outer div`

Do you want this?

```
$('.div-outer a')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.find()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.div-outer').find('a');
});
```

Also you can use descendant selector:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('.div-outer a');
    });
```

More information on [jQuery Descendant Selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/).

Comment: Why not `$('.div-outer a')`?

Comment: @KamranAhmed For readability or performance purpose maybe. Regarding performance, see: http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-vs-context-sel/38

Answer (score 0):

On document ready:

```
$('div').find('a');
```